# Apache reverse proxy couchpotato, nzbget, and sonarr, alternate http and https port

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy

I am having issues setting up a reverse proxy with ssl enable and also Apache authentication. I have att uverse and for some odd reason they have port 443 forwarded by default to the dvr box. I would like to use an alternative standard port other than 80 and also another encrypted port other than 443. I have limited knowledge when it comes to Apache. But can do all right with the right guidance. I use Ubuntu server 14.04.4. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's not a second 'official' SSL port. 443 is the universal standard.

That said, you can send encrypted data from any port, so long as the application using said port, is sending encrypted data.

Try changing the reverse proxy to use a different port (one not commonly used, such as 8991) and then forward the new Port number.

Also good reference for seeing commonly used ports: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Apache reference for  SSL setup:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html